# How do you print a whole wchar_t with spaces at once? (c++)

Tags: c++, console, wchar-t

I am trying to build a command line application, i'm at the start, and I am trying to get an wchar_t input and print it, but if I type in "foo foof" for example, it prints `foo>>> foof>>>`.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    while (1 == 1)
    {
        wchar_t afterprint[100];
        wcout << "\n>>> ";
        wcin >> afterprint;
        wcout << afterprint;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is what happens in the console:

```
>>> foo foof fofof
foo
>>> foof
>>> fofof
>>>
```

What I am expecting to happen, is for it to print what was entered, on **one** line.

Help would be highly appreciated, and I am sorry if the answer is really obvious, because I am new to C++.

Comment: `wchar_t` is a character, not a string. What about `wstring`?

Comment: Sure about `wchar_t`?

Comment: try `wchar_t afterprint[100];`

Comment: That output looks correct to me for this code ; what were you expecting and why?

Comment: If you are new to C++ then you should probably forget about `wchar_t` and focus on one of these [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Comment: Now your problem is that `std::wcin` stops at whitespaces. Instead use `std::getline`. Btw, there is no need to use `wchar_t` here, just use `std::wstring`.

Comment: I was expecting it to print what was entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the question is evolved from getting 1 char at a time problem to getting 1 word at a time problem. You can use `fgetws` to capture the whole input:

```
while (1)
{
    wchar_t afterprint[100];
    std::wcout << "\n>>> ";
    fgetws(afterprint, 100, stdin);
    std::wcout << afterprint;
}
```

Comment: Thx! i'll try that